# android studio can't debug via usb

Tags: android, android-studio, huawei-mobile-services

i try to debug my android app via usb,

and first time i run it works perfectly,

but i close android studio and restart again,it reports

(i checked **usb debug** option is open)

```
12/12 23:48:42: Launching 'app' on HUAWEI VTR-AL00.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.onhw/com.example.onhw.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.onhw/com.example.onhw.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.onhw/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.onhw/com.example.onhw.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

but it still works on virtual device

can anyone give some advices?

my phone is **HUAWEI P10**

Comment: developer option is on?

Comment: yes,and it works on first install,but when i restart android studio,it suddenly failed

Comment: I think HUAWEI P10 has some issues if you google like https://forum.xda-developers.com/p10-lite/help/usb-debugging-problem-t3704435.. did you tried to run on other devices ?

Comment: still persists the problem when connecting other device?

Comment: I don't know ..but your issues are solved right?

Comment: sry,my mistake........,i found it works on other phone and dont work on P10,mybe it is something woring with P10 system

Answer (score 0):

finally i found it was huawei's system causing the problem

because in debug mode,even i uninstall the application,it still remain the **debug-signature** of the application,but android use signature to tell if a app has been installed

so when i try to debug this app again,the **debug-signature** is still in the 
system so it can't be install

sovling way:

is to use **adb.exe** which in Sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe and execute`adb uninstall com.example.application` to totally remove the debug-signature